# Markups of Voice Two appearing on top of Voice One

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I'm engraving a guitar score and I've made a simple shortcut for drawing a circle everytime a harmonic is played, as I've seen in some music:

`hc = \markup \left-align { \draw-circle #0.3 #0.15 ##f }`

However, when I use this with tuplets in multiple voices, the markup appears above the first voice (this is an excerpt of the code where the shorcut is used):

```
upNotes = \relative c' {
  \clef "treble_8"

  %% tempo libero
  %% [...]
  \tuplet 3/2 {<as b d gs>4 <as b d gs>4  <as b d gs>4}

}

downNotes = \relative c' {

  %% tempo libero
  %% [...]
  r. b8^>^\hc b8^>^\hc b8^>^\hc( b4) r8 
  
}
```

[image: The markup appears on top of the first voice tuplets]

I know that I can make the markup show below the second voice, but I'd like it to appear on top (as in the eight-note following the triplet). What should I edit to make it so that the symbols stays *under* the first voice tuplet and not above it?

A compilable example:

```
\version "2.24.1"
\language "english"

global = {
}

hc = \markup \left-align { \draw-circle #0.3 #0.15 ##f }
hh =   \override NoteHead.style = #'harmonic-mixed

upNotes = \relative c' {
  \clef "treble_8"

  %% tempo libero
  %% [...]
  \tuplet 3/2 {<as b d g>4 <as b d g>4  <as b d g>4}

}

downNotes = \relative c' {

  %% tempo libero
  %% [...]
  \hh b8^>^\hc b8^>^\hc b8^>^\hc( b4) r8 

}

%% SCORE BLOCK
\score {
  \new ChoirStaff <<
    \new Staff = "superior" \with {
      \omit Staff.BarLine
       } <<
      % upNotes 
      \new Voice = "arriba" {
        \voiceOne
        << \global \upNotes>>
      }
      %% downNotes
      \new Voice = "abajo" {
        \voiceTwo
        << \global \downNotes >>
      }
    >>
  >>
  %% No time signature + fingering padding
  \layout {
    \context {
      \Staff
      \remove Time_signature_engraver
      \override TimeSignature.stencil = #point-stencil
      \override Fingering.staff-padding = #'()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that in this case you should probably just use the build-in articulation `\flageolet` instead (or as your definition of `\hc`).

---

A longer answer might be about something going wrong with the `outside-staff-priority`’s, and suggest an override such as:

- `\override TupletBracket.outside-staff-priority = #0`
  or
- `\override TextScript.outside-staff-priority = ##f`

---

A better answer goes the broader question; about creating a new articulation mark properly and getting LilyPond to place it in the right spot automatically — this requires a bit of Scheme. This is covered by Lazy’s answer to:  [Create a custom articulation in LilyPond](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/135184/create-a-custom-articulation-in-lilypond).