# Create a custom articulation in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

Could someone provide me with a minimal example of a new, custom articulation in LilyPond?

Let's say, for the sake of simplicity, that we use glyph "a" as the articulation, and let's call it `\newArticulation`.

Now I can use `\markup` as a workaround for creating something similar:

```
c'4^\markup{"a"}
```

but markup is not an articulation, and I would like to learn how to make a proper articulation, equivalent to the built-in ones, like `\accent` or `\trill`. Also, how would one make it turn upside down when it is below the note, like `\fermata` or `\portato`?

I've seen some examples on the LilyPond mailing list, but they seem to be very specific and mostly outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\layout {
  \context {
    \Score
    scriptDefinitions =
    #(acons
      'a
      `((stencil . ,(lambda (grob)
                      (let ((d (ly:grob-property grob 'direction UP))
                            (mstc (grob-interpret-markup
                                   grob
                                   (markup #:override '(font-encoding . latin1)
                                           #:center-align
                                           "a"))))
                        (if (= d UP)
                            mstc
                            (ly:stencil-rotate
                             mstc 180 0 (interval-center (ly:stencil-extent mstc Y)))))))
        (direction . ,UP))
      default-script-alist)
  }
}

"a" =
#(make-articulation 'a)

{
  c' d'-\a e'^\a f'_\a
  e'' f''-\a g''^\a a''_\a
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Just one question. Is it possible to move `scriptDefinitions = #(acons ...)` outside the layout context, so that this definition of a new articulation can be placed in the include file? Also, when adding multiple new articulations in this way, only the last one added works, as it always uses `default-script-alist`.

Comment: @Kresimir A layout block can be placed in an include file. If you want to be able to stepwise create multiple new articulations you can assign the result to a variable: `#(define my-script-alist default-script-alist) #(set! my-script-alist (acons ... my-script-alist)) ... \layout { \context { \Score scriptDefinitions = #my-script-alist } }`.